# Excel - How do programmatically convert 'number stored as Text' to Number?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm looking for a simple Excel VBA or formula that can convert an entire row in Excel from 'number stored as Text' to an actual Number for vlookup reasons.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: For in place conversion vba is the only way to go.  With a formula you will need to put the formula in another cell.  `=Value(A1)`

Comment: As a general rule, use INDEX(MATCH()) over VLOOKUP as it behaves in a much more predictable manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Better Approach

You should use `INDEX(MATCH)` instead of `VLOOKUP` because `VLOOKUP` behaves in an unpredictable manner which causes errors, such as the one you're presumably experiencing.

```
INDEX( <return array> , MATCH( <lookup value> , <lookup array> , 0 ) )
```

[image: INDEX MATCH example]

Using `0` as the last argument to `MATCH` means the match must be exact
[Here](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match-match/) is some more in-depth information on `INDEX(MATCH)`-ing

## Further

Add zero `+0` to convert a value to a number.
This can be (dangerously) extended with `IFERROR()` to turn non-numeric text into a zero:

`=A2+0`
`=IFERROR(A2+0,0)`

For the inverse, you can catenate an empty string `&""` to force the value to be a string.

## Notes

If `0` is not used as the last argument to `MATCH`, it will find all sorts of unexpected "matches" .. and worse, it may find a different value even when an exact match is present.

It often makes sense to do some extra work to determine if there are duplicates in the `MATCH` lookup column, otherwise the first value found will be returned (see example).

Help with `MATCH` comes from [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a), notably the matching logic the 3rd argument controls.

Comment: I've used the Index Match logic before just never in this manner. Ill give i t ago! thanks!

I was looking for a way to convert a column in place but i guess this will work as well.

Answer (score 2):

This should work if you add it before your vlookup or index/match lines:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Value = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

I did find this, but does anyone have a formula as well?

```
Sub macro() 
    Range("F:F").Select 'specify the range which suits your purpose
    With Selection 
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General" 
        .Value = .Value 
    End With 
End Sub
```

http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=64027

Comment: As Scott stated, a formula can only do this in other cells, since it cannot referencing the cell in which the formula is stored. Keyword: circular reference. But you can do it without VBA. Select Column F, call Data - Text to columns, step through the wizard, in step 3 select data format General for the whole column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub ConvertToNumber()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim cl As Range
    For Each cl In Selection.Cells
        cl.Value = CInt(cl.Value)
    Next cl
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

To use it, simply select the relevant block of cells with the mouse, and then run the macro (Alt+F8 to bring up the dialogue box). It will go through each cell in the selected range and convert whatever value it holds into a number.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a custom vlookup function that doesn't care about data formats. Put this into a module in VBA and use = VLOOK instead of = VLOOKUP

```
Public Function VLook(sValue As String, rDest As Range, iColNo As Integer)

' custom vlookup that's insensitive to data formats

Dim iLastRow As Long
Dim wsDest As Worksheet

Set wsDest = Sheets(rDest.Parent.Name)

iLastRow = wsDest.Range(wsDest.Cells(100000, rDest.Column).Address).End(xlUp).Row

If iLastRow < rDest.Row + rDest.Rows.Count Then
    For X = rDest.Column To rDest.Column + rDest.Columns.Count
        If wsDest.Cells(100000, X).End(xlUp).Row > iLastRow Then iLastRow = wsDest.Cells(100000, X).End(xlUp).Row
    Next X
End If

sValue = UCase(Application.Clean(Trim(sValue)))

For X = rDest.Row To iLastRow

    If UCase(Application.Clean(Trim(wsDest.Cells(X, rDest.Column)))) = sValue Then
        VLookDM = wsDest.Cells(X, rDest.Column + iColNo - 1)
        Exit For
    End If

Next X

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is using the built-in function =VALUE(TEXT_TO_CONVERT_TO_STRING).