# Inconsistent Excel VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an odd problem with some formulas in my Excel sheet for fantasy football:

In one table, I have a list of the picks and players drafted in one year. The columns are as follows: CO = Player name, CP = Year, CQ = Round, CR = Pick, CS = Owner.

Column CO is hand-entered with names, CP is hand-entered with the year 2011, and CQ is hand-entered with the draft round (the first ten are round 1, the second ten are round 2, etc).

Column CR is a formula that calculates the pick number based on the round number and the row it's in. The formula in cell CR2 looks like this: "=CQ2+MOD(ROW(CR2)-2,10)/100+0.01" and evaluates to "1.01". CR3's formula would evaluate to "1.02", CR4 would evaluate to "1.03", etc.

EDIT: Here's a picture of the top 15 rows of this sheet: [picks sheet here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBlYI.jpg)

On another sheet, I have a 5x10 grid of VLOOKUP formulas where I try to list which owner has which picks. The VLOOKUP formula for each of the cells in this grid is as follows: "=VLOOKUP(1.01,Picks2011[[Pick]:[Owner]],2,FALSE)", where "1.01" is the name of the pick from column CR, "Picks2011" is the name of the table in the previous sheet, and "[[Pick]:[Owner]]" are the columns in the table "Picks2011". This example formula correctly outputs the name of the owner who had pick 1.01 in 2011.

EDIT: Here's a picture of the grid with the failing cells: [grid showing the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TUP8.jpg)

The problem is that certain cells in this sheet are giving me an "#N/A" for no particular reason. For example, pick 2.01 outputs correctly, but pick 2.02 outputs #N/A, and pick 2.03 outputs correctly again. There doesn't seem to be any kind of a pattern to the errors. I've tried deleting both tables and recreating them from scratch, and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with them.

Comment: Can you please post an image of the data?

Comment: You will find that the values appear rounded but in fact have values in the lower decimals, for example it might show `2.02` but the actual value might be `2.01999999999995` so it does not find the match.

Comment: Added some pictures for more information.

Scott, I've heard of numbers doing that in Excel, but why would that be the case for some of them but not others?

EDIT: One more note is that I've done the same grid procedure every year since 2011, giving each year it's own sheet, and all of the other sheets for other years work perfectly.

Comment: Floating point decimal.  It is a known issue.  Wrap the initial formula in a round formula:  `=ROUND(=CQ2+MOD(ROW(CR2)-2,10)/100+0.01,2)`

Comment: Add some sample data that would help fixing the issue

Comment: Scott, I tried adding the ROUND formula to the grid and the results did not change for any of the 5x10 cells.

Praveen, I'm new to this site...what's the best way to add sample data?

Comment: Whoops, I wrapped the wrong INITIAL formula in a ROUND function. That did the trick! Not sure why it was so irregular and only on the one year, but whatever...thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: @Travis If you're online again, would you mind Answering with Scott's comment? Seems like a useful addition to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Travis... I noticed that the VLOOKUP formula is pointing to a grid formatted as a table, which I love since it makes it easier than having to deal with specifying and anchoring ranges.. however, the fact that the N/A issue you are running into appears to happen every other row, makes me wonder if the formatting on those culprit rows is different than the formatting on those rows returning the values you'd expect.  Maybe check that, and as a way of troubleshooting try copying data from the working rows into the failing rows to see what value your vlookup returns.. worth the shot.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, but look at the picture of the grid that I posted earlier. You'll see that the errors are erratic: in columns 2 and 3, the errors are all even-numbers. However, in columns 4, 5, and 6, the errors are in the 3rd and 7th rows only. This irregularity is what makes this problem so weird.

Comment: Wondering if the issue is tied to the formula used to calculate the pick decimal number.  Have you considered pasting the results as values and see if there is an impact to the vlookup results?  If it does, but you need to keep a formula to calculate the pick, I could provide other suggestion that rely on Integer numbers or even decimal numbers without rounding.. just a thought…

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using an `INDEX(MATCH)` construct instead of `VLOOKUP`.

Unfortunately `VLOOKUP` behaves pretty unpredictably if you're not working with just two columns of unique strings.

I wrote an answer here ( [Excel - How do programmatically convert 'number stored as Text' to Number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37891868/excel-how-do-programmatically-convert-number-stored-as-text-to-number/37929289#37929289) ) which may be just what you're looking for!

```
INDEX ( <return array> , MATCH ( <lookup value> , <lookup array> , 0) )
```