# Not finding cell in VLOOKUP search

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Sorry for the weird question but I can't figure this one out.

I have an excel sheet that I use cell C4 to search other sheets.  For the most part it finds what I am searching for, however some of the data is not coming up and gives me a "#N/A" error.  I have cut and part for the sheet I need to search from and the search inquiry is correct.

I am using
 `=VLOOKUP("*" & C4 & "*", BBDishwashers!A1:D162,1,FALSE)`

Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Can you give an example of your Data?

Comment: N/A means no match, Vlookup did not find the C4 you are looking for in A1:D162

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided. I suggest uploading a workbook that clearly demonstrates the problem to some public file sharing site (eg Dropbox; OneDrive) and then post a link here. Be sure to remove any sensitive information from the workbook before posting.

Comment: On a related matter, did you mean to lookup a value in column A of A:D and then return the same value? Your third parameter is a **1** which means lookup in column A and return the same value from column A.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the worksheet.  I am trying to get the info from the first cell column

Comment: If you copied that data from a web page there is a good chance that there are rogue characters like non-breaking spaces. Pick a value that you think should have matched and examine it more closely.

Comment: Can you give an example of a working and non-working lookup value? To @Jeeped 's point, try adding another column which simply calls [`CLEAN`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CLEAN-function-26f3d7c5-475f-4a9c-90e5-4b8ba987ba41) on the first, then lookup from that EDIT: changed link to exact article.

Comment: @nobb666 Have you ever tried to copy the information from a screenshot in order to debug something?  If you have, I'll bet you'll never provide such a source for others to try to help you again. To say nothing of the fact that your screenshot still would not allow reproduction of your problem.

Comment: @nobb666  Working from your uploaded workbook, the reason VLOOKUP is returning NA, in those instances shown on the DISHWASHER sheet, is either because the item in C4 does not exist , or because your VLOOKUP is looking in the wrong column

Comment: Why aren't you trying to direct (non-wildcard) match on BBDish!C:C? e.g. `=INDEX(BBDish!A:A, MATCH(C4, BBDish!C:C, 0))`

Comment: @nobb666 Be aware that VLOOKUP will always look in the first column of the range.  The column argument is the value that is being returned.  As others have pointed out, `INDEX(MATCH ..` may be more appropriate here.

Comment: Sorry I sent the wrong file.  Bad day today.https://1drv.ms/x/s!AvzXyiSyMirHklWuzMNjFf7WyOgl

Comment: @nobb666 -Good luck with your project!

Comment: @nobb666 Again, the item you have in C4 does not exist on the Leons Dishwashers page.  So NA would be expected.  The return value BB seems correct.

Comment: @Ron Rossenfeld.  When you type in "DW80M9960UG" in C4 in DISHWASHERS i get an error code in all ranges.  However the BestBuy range (BBDishwashers" do indeed have the time in it.

Comment: @nobb666 Not so on the workbook you uploaded in column A. That value appears on BBDishwashers!C30 and D30, but, as I wrote, your VLOOKUP is not looking for a match in those columns.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld  when I put in "SHE3AR72" (which is in BBDishwashers C19) it finds it and places everything correctly.

Comment: @nobb666 Huh?  Do you not understand that VLOOKUP looks in the **FIRST** column of the array?  Read the documentation.  Just because that value happens to be in C19, does not mean that is where VLOOKUP is matching.  The reason the formula works is because the value is in A19.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld  Crap, that I didn't get until you said it.  I see what everyone is talking about then.  You made it simple by letting me know the cell .  OK, now to figure out something else to do the search.

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks, your suggestion works.

Comment: @nobb666- Glad to hear it worked out. You can make that a bracketed wildcard or a 'starts with' wildcard as well. Fort 'starts with' use `=INDEX(BBDish!A:A, MATCH(C4&"*", BBDish!C:C, 0))`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `INDEX(MATCH)` instead of `VLOOKUP` as described here:
[Excel - How do programmatically convert 'number stored as Text' to Number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37891868/excel-how-do-programmatically-convert-number-stored-as-text-to-number/37929289#37929289)

Unfortunately, `VLOOKUP` behaves in a rather unpredictable manner.

Comment: What do you mean by * `VLOOKUP` behaves in a rather unpredictable manner*.  Can you provide an example?  I have always been able to predict the behavior based on the documentation for the function.

Comment: Your link is completely irrelevant. The OP wants a wildcard search so this is not an issue of converting text-that-look-like-a-number to true numbers although it may possibly be the other way around.

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon on SO. Reproduce the relevant portion(s) of the linked material in your response. Leave the link for further reference or not as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

You should make that a  direct (non-wildcard) match on BBDish!C:C,

```
=INDEX(BBDish!A:A, MATCH(C4, BBDish!C:C, 0))
```

You can make that a bracketed wildcard with

```
=INDEX(BBDish!A:A, MATCH("*"&C4&"*", BBDish!C:C, 0))
```

... or a 'starts with' wildcard as well. For 'starts with' use,

```
=INDEX(BBDish!A:A, MATCH(C4&"*", BBDish!C:C, 0))
```