# Convert number stored as text to number - Decimals

Tags: vba, excel

I realise that this is sort of a duplicate question, but the solutions mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37891868/excel-how-do-programmatically-convert-number-stored-as-text-to-number) question don't work for me completely.

My current code is as follows

```
Sub ConvertTextToNumber()
Dim Area As Range, C As Range
Set Area = Sheets("Tank 3").Range("C7:L7,B8:B17,C20:L20,B21:B69")

For Each C In Area
    If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Celle) = False And C <> "" Then
        C.NumberFormat = "0.0"
        C.Value = C.Value + 0
    End If
Next C

End Sub
```

This works fine on integers, but the moment the number stored as text is a decimal such as 0,1 or 0,2, it simply converts the number to 1 or 2 respectively.

I've tried using `C.value = c.value` after setting the NumberFormat to numbers or general, but that does nothing for me

Update: It seems the problem lies with the separators. I have to use "," as the decimal separator, and this makes the sub malfunction. If I swap the decimal separator to "." the sub runs fine.

Comment: Try C.NumberFormat = "0.00"

Comment: because the number format is only `"0"` it doesn't show the full number

Comment: I was really hoping that it was that easy, but no, it still disregards the 0,1 and sees it as 1. 0,2 is seen as 2, 0,3 as 3 and so forth

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with the numerical format.  IE in the US "." is used as the decimal separator where as other languages use ",".  This would not be part of your cell format but your OS numerical formats.

Comment: hmm then `= CDbl(C)` or `= Val(Replace(C, ",", "."))`

Comment: I've set the decimal separator to be "," but for the sake of testing I swapped it to be "." instead, and it actually worked. That's no good for me though, as all other computers this sheet will be used on uses "," as the separator

Comment: ugly work around.  Strip the number as text in the format your excel will recognize it in and dump it in a cell.  Then take that cell and use it in a math operation like +0 or *1.  Excel should then take the result as a number and it will be formatted in a way that matches the needs of the set up of the system you are using it on?

Comment: I think I've got an even uglier workaround going. The ranges containing the decimal numbers will always be the same place, and are guaranteed to contain decimals, so if Excel insists on multiplying the numbers by 10, then I can divide the numbers by 10 rather than add 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `Range.FormulaLocal` to automatically cast a string to a number based on your regional settings:

```
Sub ConvertTextToNumber()
  Dim Area As Range, C As Range
  Set Area = Sheets("Tank 3").Range("C7:L7,B8:B17,C20:L20,B21:B69")

  For Each C In Area
      C.FormulaLocal = C.Value
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, this is becoming increasingly simple. It seems this solution works regardless of what settings are being used then? If so this would be the simplest and most versatile solution

Comment: If the number is a string, the number is parsed with the format rendered in Excel. If not, the value is not altered.

Comment: That is perfect. And with a much simpler code, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can [change the separators through VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-decimalseparator-property-excel):

```
Sub ChangeSeparator()
    Application.DecimalSeparator = "."
    Application.ThousandsSeparator = ","
    Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
    ConvertTextToNumber
    Application.UseSystemSeparators = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The separators are already set like that through the normal settings, and will be like that on all computers that this sheet will be used on, but that exact thing is causing all the trouble. The sub seems to do exactly what it's supposed to do if I swap the separators to "," as the thousand separator and "." as the decimal separator. Even if I do that from VBA, company policies does not allow me to use the US standard. I have to use "," as the decimal separator.

Comment: @Christian Emil Johansen you can use "." as your decimal separator, then call your function and switch back to your local settings again. Not tested though.

Comment: That's actually pretty good. Using `Sub ChangeSeparator()
    Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
    Application.DecimalSeparator = "."
    Application.ThousandsSeparator = ","
    Call ConvertTextToNumber
    Application.DecimalSeparator = ","
    Application.ThousandsSeparator = "."
End Sub` works for me as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use a little trick and that would be to import all the numbers as text in to your code then manipulate it and spit it back out. The comma confuses english conversions and would see 2,0 as 20. Anyway here's how you could do it

```
Sub ConvertTextToNumber()

  Dim Area As Range, C As Range
  Dim InNumAsStr As String

  Set Area = Sheets("all").Range("A1:B10")

    For Each C In Area
      InNumAsStr = C.Text '*** force the value to be a string type ***
      '***swap out any commas with decimal points ***
      InNumAsStr = Replace(InNumAsStr, ",", ".") 
      C.NumberFormat = "0.0"
      C.Value = InNumAsStr
   Next C

End Sub
```

Comment: That right there is what I'm looking for. Brilliant, thank you, it does wonders for me