# Need to create duplicate rows when using VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, function, ms-office

I am working with data where I need to pull from other sheets to create a Master sheet. I need to lookup two of the same information then populate different fields with other information that varies. For example,

```
Lastname.....Firstname........Date.....AM/PM.......Goal    
Smith.........Kyle...........8/8/18..............PM........Height <br/>
Smith.........Kyle...........8/8/18..............PM........Weight <br/>
```

Right now it is hand coded using VLOOKUP:

```
Lastname........Firstname.........Date....................AM/PM............Goal    
='Data1'!A2.....='Data1'!B2.....='Data1'!C2.....='Data1'!D2.....='Data1'!**H2**
='Data1'!A2.....='Data1'!B2.....='Data1'!C2.....='Data1'!D2.....='Data1'!**L2**
```

I want to be able to apply this pattern all the way down, with two copies for `Lastname`, `Firstname`, `Date`, `AM/PM`, but with different goals. The problem is that Excel keeps moving down immediately to the next cell, going from referencing A3 straight to A4 without repeating A3 for me first.

Is there a way to code around this? Or maybe a completely different function?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to simply have two `Goal` columns, simplifying your sheet? Alternatively, don't include duplicate data in rows beyond the first and index from the first discovered row. As a general statement, I'd also recommend using an [`INDEX(MATCH)` style over `VLOOKUP`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37929289/4541045) if you can make the jump

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using INDIRECT() and FLOOR(ROW()/2,1) to create an every-other pattern with your equations.  It looks like this:

```
2 =INDIRECT("'Data1'!A" & 1+FLOOR(ROW()/2,1)) ... =INDIRECT("'Data1'!"&IF(FLOOR(ROW()/2,1)=ROW()/2,"H","L")&FLOOR(ROW()/2,1)+1)
3 =INDIRECT("'Data1'!A" & 1+FLOOR(ROW()/2,1)) ... =INDIRECT("'Data1'!"&IF(FLOOR(ROW()/2,1)=ROW()/2,"H","L")&FLOOR(ROW()/2,1)+1)
```