# Excel Shipping Cost Calculator Based On Table

Tags: excel

I am trying to turn the following table into a "calculator", so any user can input information (Zone & Weight) and get the shipping cost. I have the table set up like this:
[Shipping Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rYCn.png)

I am using the following formula to try and piece this together, but I am receiving an error for more than 64 layers of nesting.

`=IF(M2<2,5.99,IF(AND(M2<=3,T2<=6),5.99,IF(AND(M2<=3,T2=7),6,IF(AND(M2<=3,T2=8),6.29,IF(AND(M2<=4,T2<=5),5.99,IF(AND(M2<=4,T2=6),6.05,IF(AND(M2<=4,T2=7),6.44,IF(AND(M2<=4,T2=8),6.74,IF(AND(M2<=5,T2<=4),5.99,IF(AND(M2<=5,T2=5),6.15,IF(AND(M2<=5,T2=6),6.41,IF(AND(M2<=5,T2=7),6.74,IF(AND(M2<=5,T2=8),7.11,IF(AND(M2<=6,T2<=3),5.99,IF(AND(M2<=6,T2=4),6.01,IF(AND(M2<=6,T2=5),6.33,IF(AND(M2<=6,T2=6),6.56,IF(AND(M2<=6,T2=7),9.91,IF(AND(M2<=6,T2=8),7.25,IF(AND(M2<=7,T2<=3),5.99,IF(AND(M2<=7,T2=4),6.1,IF(AND(M2<=7,T2=5),6.52,IF(AND(M2<=7,T2=6),6.68,IF(AND(M2<=7,T2=7),7.09,IF(AND(M2<=7,T2=8),7.59,IF(AND(M2<=8,T2<=3),5.99,IF(AND(M2<=8,T2=4),6.26,IF(AND(M2<=8,T2=5),6.65,IF(AND(M2<=8,T2=6),6.88,IF(AND(M2<=8,T2=7),7.32,IF(AND(M2<=8,T2=8),7.85,IF(AND(M2<=9,T2<=3),5.99,IF(AND(M2<=9,T2=4),6.35,IF(AND(M2<=9,T2=5),6.7,IF(AND(M2<=9,T2=6),7.03,IF(AND(M2<=9,T2=7),7.61,IF(AND(M2<=9,T2=8),8.26,IF(AND(M2<=10,T2=2),7.16,IF(AND(M2<=10,T2=3),7.6,IF(AND(M2<=10,T2=4),8.42,IF(AND(M2<=10,T2=5),9.1,IF(AND(M2<=10,T2=6),9.47,IF(AND(M2<=10,T2=7),10.64,IF(AND(M2<=10,T2=8),11.64,IF(AND(M2<=11,T2=2),7.47,IF(AND(M2<=11,T2=3),7.77,IF(AND(M2<=11,T2=4),8.51,IF(AND(M2<=11,T2=5),9.15,IF(AND(M2<=11,T2=6),9.79,IF(AND(M2<=11,T2=7),11.52,IF(AND(M2<=11,T2=8),12.41,IF(AND(M2<=12,T2=2),7.59,IF(AND(M2<=12,T2=3),8.09,IF(AND(M2<=12,T2=4),8.59,IF(AND(M2<=12,T2=5),9.28,IF(AND(M2<=12,T2=6),10.14,IF(AND(M2<=12,T2=7),11.99,IF(AND(M2<=12,T2=8),12.99,IF(AND(M2<=13,T2=2),7.77,IF(AND(M2<=13,T2=3),8.1,IF(AND(M2<=13,T2=4),8.78,IF(AND(M2<=13,T2=5),9.54,IF(AND(M2<=13,T2=6),10.45,IF(AND(M2<=13,T2=7),12.84,IF(AND(M2<=13,T2=8),13.83`)

I am not sure how to get this done with a VLookup, as there is multiple criteria that must be met. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Aargh. Refer to INDEX and MATCH formulae!

Comment: Here's a reasonable demo of `INDEX(MATCH)`-ing I wrote on another question which may do what you want https://stackoverflow.com/a/37929289/4541045 . You may also have a better time doing your calculation in two steps to make it clearer (one column checks Weight, the other Zone, and then are combined in a third) or similar.

Comment: Also suggest you give a bit more detail. Looks like you're not necessarily looking for exact matches?

Comment: Thank you! Basically, I am trying to take the weights and zones of shipments we sent in the last month, and see what the cost would be with our new rates. Column A represents the weight OR LOWER, so, if, for example the weight is 2.5 lbs and the shipment in going to zone 7, it will cost $6

Answer (score 1):

Weight is in M2, Zone is in T2.

```
=index(B4:H18, match(ceiling(M2, 1), A4:A18, 0), 1, match(T2, B3:H3, 0))
```

No proof-of-concept image supplied as no sample data provided outside of image.